# Can't Find Maintenance.flag

Tags: error, magmi, installation

1. I recently downloaded Magmi for my Magento installation.
2. Put Magmi folder in Magento root directory
3. As soon as I refresh my site it shows **Service Temporarily
   Unavailable**.
4. Downloaded full Magento installation and searched for maintenance
   flag in local copy.
5. Found nothing.

Please help I cannot get my site out of this state.

site: [truesupplement.com](http://truesupplement.com/)

Comment: Are you sure that this is a maintenance.flag-issue? You could check your apache error log additionally. Do you have FTP or SSH access to the server? Maybe your FTP client does not show maintenance.flag file by default

Comment: Your website is loading fine now. Did you resolve the issue and if so, what was the cause?

Answer (score 1):

If this is maintenance.flag related, what you **don't** want at the moment is maintenance.flag

Open up your directory where Magento is installed and remove or rename the maintenance.flag file in there.

Flush cache.

To me though this sounds like it could be some other error.